# cocos2d-x 3.0 render texture

Tags: textures, cocos2d-x, render

I am unable to create a sprite from render texture in cocos2d-x 3.0 which was possible in 2.2.x.

here is the code in 3.0 that I use.

```
Sprite* HelloWorld::createNewTexture(float width, float height)
{
    auto rt = RenderTexture::create(width, height);
    rt->beginWithClear(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    rt->end();

    auto s = Sprite::createWithTexture(rt->getSprite()->getTexture());

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is obtaining a sprite with no image and only a background color then you can use this code

```
Sprite* HelloWorld::createNewTexture(float width, float height)
{
    auto s = Sprite::create();
    s->setTextureRect(Rect(0,0,width,height));
    s->setColor(Color3B::BLUE);
    s->setOpacity(128);

    return s;
}
```

However If you have to use RenderTexture then you should add a retain to it:

```
auto rt = RenderTexture::create(width, height);
rt->retain(); <--- ADD THIS LINE
rt->beginWithClear(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
rt->end();
```

in your code. It works for me with cocos2d-x 3.0. More info at this [link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/53167?r=53650#message-53650).

Comment: thanks... but is there a way to use rendertexture at all? I dont know why I get a blank screen. In 2.2.2 the code use to work fine.

Comment: ya. thanks that works :). I never used retain before. Altho I am still not getting the exact result of 3.0 as this guy http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/53244?r=53799